# connect signalr server from dotnet4 console app

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr

I have a signalR server running on AspNetCore 2.1.0-preview2-final at `https://localhost:44384/chathub`. My web client and dotnetcore console app connects to the server successfully but dotnet4 console app is FAILED.

SignalR server Startup.cs\Configure:

```
app.UseSignalR(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chathub");
        });
```

web client running in the same signalR server: SUCCESSFUL

```
const connection = new signalR.HubConnection(
"/chathub",
{
    logger: signalR.LogLevel.Information
});
```

dotnetcore console app (Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client 1.0.0-preview2-final): SUCCESSFUL

```
_connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
             .WithUrl("https://localhost:44384/chathub")
             .WithConsoleLogger()
             .Build();
```

dotnet4 console app (Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client 2.2.3.0): FAILED

```
hubConnection = new HubConnection("https://localhost:44384/chathub");

            hubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("ChatHub");

            await hubConnection.Start();
```

The exception is:

```
StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent,...
```

Any idea please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SignalR 2.2.3 is not compatible with SignalR for ASP.NET Core. You cannot use the old client with the new server or the old server with the new client.

Comment: sweet thanks. just need to install System.Numerics.Vectors (4.5.0-preview2-26406-04) and Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client (1.0.0-preview2-final) from nuget

Comment: I think the client package should pull all the dependencies you need.